# CSS: How to move a div above another another one?

Tags: css

I have two div, A and B. I would like to put element B above element A using CSS. 
I can warp them in a parent div if it's needed. 
I have tried several things (float, vertical-align), without success.

What I have:

A

B

What I want:

B

A

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Try `display:flex; flex-dimension: column;` on a container widget and `order: <sequence-number>` on `A`, `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this with [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) attribute**, whenever you assign a [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) display to the parent element.

So in order to do this, you just have to create two `div` and wrap them within a parent, then **make your parent `display` as `flex`** by then, children of that parent will follow the `flex` rules. One of the available attributes for `flex` items is `order` which you can define for each of the children and **gave them sequence number (`1, 2, 3, ...`) then the child with the lower value will appear first and so on**.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first {
  order: 2;
}

.second {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">A</div>
  <div class="second">B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the 2 text divs in a container

```
body {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 sans-serif;
}
.text-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.text-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em; /* same as line-height */
}
.text-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

<div class="text-wrap">
    <div class="text-1">
        AAA
    </div>
    <div class="text-2">
        BBB
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.child{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">a</div>
  <div class="child">b</div>
</div>
```

**Using flex-direction you can move the children of a container**